# Title on a page with custom template

Tags: wordpress

Good day!
I have a strange issue with Wordpress 5.1.1. I have two pages with custom templates, a homepage and a blog page. On other pages I use standard template. And on standard pages I can see page title like About us - Sitename, Contacts - Sitename.
But on these custom pages it's empty! I can see only Sitename and title tag is empty. What it can be?
Also, I use custom WP_Query on a blog page.

UPD

This is my custom blog page:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Template Name: Статьи
 */
$page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'paged'=> $page ));
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
) );
get_header(); 
the_title();
?>

<div id="blog_cards" class="ui grid">
    <div class="sixteen wide column">
            <div id="categories">
                <?php 
                foreach( $categories as $category ) {
                    $category_link = sprintf( 
                        '<a class="category" href="%1$s" alt="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
                        esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ),
                        esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts in %s', 'textdomain' ), $category->name ) ),
                        esc_html( $category->name )
                    );

                    echo $category_link;
                }
                ?>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sixteen wide column">
        <div class="ui two cards">
        <?php
        if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
            while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="card">
                <div class="image">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                  <div class="header"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title();?></a></div>
                  <div class="meta">
                    <a><?php the_time('d.m.Y');?></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="description">
                    <?php the_content();?>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="extra content">
                <?php 
                $post_cats = get_the_category();
                foreach( $post_cats as $category ) {
                    $category_link = sprintf( 
                        '<a class="category" href="%1$s" alt="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
                        esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ),
                        esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts in %s', 'textdomain' ), $category->name ) ),
                        esc_html( $category->name )
                    );

                    echo $category_link;
                }
                ?>
                </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile;?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sixteen wide column">
        <?php if (function_exists('wp_corenavi')) wp_corenavi(array( 'wp_query' => $wp_query )); ?>
    </div>
    <?php 

    endif; ?>
</div>
<?php
do_action( 'storefront_sidebar' );
get_footer();
```

Also, I tried to call `the_title()` and it returned page title in a body of template. But title tag is empty.
And I use standard storefront theme for woocomerce.

Comment: Please post the code of your custom templates

Comment: you have to use the_title(); on the template to show the page/post title.

Comment: Can you please move  get_header(); and the_title(); before $page, and can i have your site link if possible..

Comment: Thank you very much, Darsh! I've just put get_header() on the top and that's it! Works perfect!

Comment: i am posting it as an answer please accept it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please move  **`get_header()`** on the top of the page (before $page).